# FilePond setting an initial file

Tags: filepond

I have a question and an issue with FilePond.

I am currently using FilePond in combination with Doka and want to load an initial image, i added the image via. files: [] with an url to my server where the file is located at.

The file load works, except for one thing:

I am using file type validation and if i am loading the initial file using an url the file type will always be text/html, this results in not loading the image and i am not able to change it using doka.

If i add text/html to the file type validation i am not able to use the image preview.

Does someone know if there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server you're loading the file from isn't assigning the correct mime-type to the file. Best to make sure it does.

If you can't change that you could load it with `fetch`, adjust the `type` property and then add it to FilePond.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to see if it is a mime type issue with the file but the type seems to be correct. I tried using a generic image (https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/957C/production/_111686283_pic1.png) from bbc to test if this image can be loaded, unfortunately it can't be added either.

These settings are active: allowFileTypeValidation: true,  acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'] -> all images will result in this error. https://i.ibb.co/mJLbh8p/image.png